# exception was thrown: setState() or markNeedsBuild() called during build

Tags: flutter, dart, exception, flutter-getx

I'm little bit confusion about the this `exception was thrown: setState() or markNeedsBuild() called during build.` and I know it get resolved by this `WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((timeStamp) {});` code of line , but I want to understand why it happens, and why we use this `addPostFrameCallback`  . I want to know deep concept about this exception with meaning , because this exception make me mad at sometimes , my code goes well suddenly it comes up. I don't know deeper but I think It is related to our state, I think our state is not build properly and the state got called again it makes a loop. that's why flutter throws this exception.

I have noticed, when I was newbie to the flutter , I put this `setState()` inside `build` method so this exception came up. where I got idea , This makes loops for states, all we know that `setState()` is use for rebuilding the states and call `build` method of widget tree , which rebuild our widgets with dynamic value.

If I have misconception about this exception , I would love to be clear by anyone.

I'm gonna attach the code below , where exception produced when goes to the screen for second time:

```
class UpcomingAppointmentsScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  UpcomingAppointmentsScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  AppointmentController controller = Get.find();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    controller.getupcomingAppointments(); //At this line exception comes up.

    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: MColors.colorBackgroundLight,
      body: Stack(
        children: [
          Obx(() {
            if (controller.upcomingAppointments.isEmpty &&
                !(controller.upcomingAppoinmentLoadingState.value)) {
              return Center(
                child: Text(
                  'No upcoming appointments found',
                  style: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.black,
                      fontSize: FontSize.largeTextSize,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                ),
              );
            } else {
              return ListView.builder(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(3),
                  itemCount: controller.upcomingAppointments.length,
                  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                    var appointment = controller.upcomingAppointments[index];
                    return AppointmentCard(appointment);
                  });
            }
          }),
          Obx(() {
            return Visibility(
                visible: controller.upcomingAppoinmentLoadingState.value,
                child: Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator()));
          })
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Api call and set data to list of models :

```
 getupcomingAppointments() {
    upcomingAppoinmentLoadingState.value = true;
    ApiCalls.appointmentsHistory().then((value) {
     
      List list = value['Upcoming Appointments'];
      upcomingAppointments.clear();
      list.forEach((element) {
        upcomingAppointments.add(AppointmentsData.fromJson(element));
      });

      upcomingAppoinmentLoadingState.value = false;
    }).catchError((onError) {
      upcomingAppoinmentLoadingState.value = false;
    });
  }
```

Comment: can you include code-snippet that will reproduce the same error

Comment: Sure, I have updated the question , you may check now

Comment: Can you include getupcomingAppointments() function too please ?

Comment: Updated again , please review now